# How to understand type inference of "ap = liftM2 id"?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

```hs
id     :: a -> a
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c

ap     :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b    
ap     =  liftM2 id
```

Could you help explain how the type of `ap` is inferred when `liftM2` is applied to `id`?  Moreover, is it valid to ask the equivalent question but more specifically how `(a -> b -> c) -> m a` is reduced to `m (a -> b)` in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets try to find out what `liftM2 id`'s type should be. First of all, we change the type parameter in `id`, so that we can fix this a little bit easier.

```
id     :: x -> x
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
```

Next, we add additional parentheses in `liftM2` and remember that `a -> b -> c` is actually `a -> (b -> c)`:

```
id     :: x -> x
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> (b -> c)) -> m a -> (m b -> m c)
```

Now we shift `x -> x` to line it up with other types in `liftM2`:

```
id     ::               x -> x
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> (b -> c)) -> m a -> (m b -> m c)
```

Ok. This tells us that `a ~ (b -> c)` in `liftM2 id`, or:

```
id     ::               (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => ((b -> c) -> (b -> c)) 
                    -> m (b -> c) -> (m b -> m c)
```

Now we can use those specialized versions:

```
liftM2 id :: Monad m => m (b -> c) -> (m b -> m c)
```

We drop the superfluous parentheses and end up with the correct type:

```
liftM2 id :: Monad m => m (b -> c) -> m b -> m c
```

Comment: Ha. I composed *exactly* this answer, pretty close to word for word (a few minutes late), but you lined up the types better.

Comment: You've reminded me again that `a -> b -> c` is actually `a -> (b -> c)`, i.e. the type inference is right associative, and you're a minute ahead of `@Tikhon Jelvis`. Thank you both. Accepted.

Answer (score 4):

`id` has the type `a -> a`. The first question is how can we *unify* `a -> a` with the type of `liftM2`'s argument, `(a -> b -> c)`? The trick is to replace the `a` in `a -> a` with `(a -> b)` giving us `(a -> b) -> (a -> b)` or, equivalently, `(a -> b) -> a -> b`. (As a neat side note, this is the type of `$`, which means `$` is just `id` with a restricted type!)

Now we combine `(a -> b) -> a -> b` with `liftM2`'s whole type:

```
Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
```

We replace `a1` with `a -> b`, `a2` with `a` and `r` with `b` giving us:

```
Monad m => ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

Finally, once we apply `liftM2` to `id`, the result has the same type minus the first argument:

```
liftM2 id :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

And there we are: the type of `ap`.

A good intuition for this is based on my earlier observation about `$`. `$` is the normal function application operator; `ap` is function application *lifted over a monad*. It makes sense that `liftM2 ($)` gives you `ap` because that's what `ap` fundamentally means... and `id` is just a version of `$` with a more general type.